# Remove IPTables Rule after 24 hours

Tags: centos, iptables

I wish to add a rule to iptables, and have it automatically removed after 24 hours.

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: Type `man at` into your terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `iptables` rule valid for one day. For example:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -m time --utc --datestart 2017-06-29T00:00 --datestop 2017-06-29T23:59 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to crontab script with such content that should start in 24 hours:

```
#!/bin/bash

if[ (iptables-save | grep -c "<your rule>") == "1"]; then
iptables -D <your rule>
fi
```